# Mandrill reject reason unassigned

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5.3, mandrill

I was trying to send mail via mandrill using laravel. Now everything is working fine when i am trying to send mail it says send on the laravel application but the problem is in the outbound section of mandrill it says

```
reject reason unassigned
```

Added the screenshot for more assistance.

[image]

Now i have troubleshooted and its said that its your problem with domain but i have checked and it is fine 
screen shot attached too. 
[image]

Comment: Did you figure out how to resolve this issue?